# React not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set up a new react project with "npx create-react-app name". I tried to clean all of the files I didn't need, except for the ones that were necessary of course, but now nothing displays. I've had trouble with react-router and routes when it didn't work too.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>KassaSysteem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home = () => {
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder='your email here'/>
    <input placeholder='displayname'/>
    <input type="password" placeholder='your password here'/>
  </form>
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Login() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>login</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

These are all of the files I have, except for the CSS files. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please comment.

Comment: when you run your app there is not any error ?

Comment: Nothing, no error just no display

Comment: Home doesn't return anything?

Comment: doesn't help, login does return something. Is there something wrong with the routers and routes?

Comment: if you delete router still it would not work ? just return some simple component in App

Comment: It is stuck at loading cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install react-router-dom old version that is 5.2.0,

or you can run
npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0
and restart your server that means npm start and its worked and Your home component should be like this.

```
const Home = () => {
return(      
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder='your email here'/>
    <input placeholder='displayname'/>
    <input type="password" placeholder='your password here'/>
 </form>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use the latest version (v6) you use this code

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home () {
  return (
    <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder='your email here'/>
        <input placeholder='displayname'/>
        <input type="password" placeholder='your password here'/>
  </form>
  )
}

export default App;
```